# How do I get my image header to resize? It's cut off on mobile but looks fine on desktop

Tags: css, background, banner, image-size, responsive

I'm looking for some CSS help. I am working on my church's website, and I am trying to get the mobile version of my supposedly responsive theme to resize header images. Right now the header image doesn't seem to resize, or at least not completely.

Website: http://www.rochestertrinity.com/kids.html

What I'm hoping to get is to have the header image scale to the exact width of whatever the display size is. So things would look essentially the same on desktop, but on mobile the user would see the entire header image. I've attached a mock up image of what I see now and what I'd like to see.

[image of what I see vs what I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgokC.jpg)

I'm not a CSS expert, but I suspect the code that manages this is in one of the following snippets:

```css
/* Tall Header Page */
.tall-header-page .banner-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.tall-header-page .banner-wrap .container {
  height: 450px;
}
.tall-header-page .banner-wrap .banner h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  padding-top: 65px;
}
```

OR

```css
/* Banner */
.banner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 55px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff url('default-bg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.banner-wrap:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: ' ';
}
.banner-wrap .container {
  display: table;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.banner-wrap .banner {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.banner-wrap .banner h2 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  word-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
.banner-wrap .banner p {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: .03em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .button-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #ff8345;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button:hover .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #e56525;
}
```

I hope someone can help.

Thanks!

UPDATE 2016-04-22

tall-header.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body class='tall-header-page  wsite-theme-light'>

  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="paris-header">
      <div class="container">
       <label class="hamburger"><span></span></label>
       <div class="logo">{logo}</div>
        <div class="nav desktop-nav">{menu}</div>
      </div><!-- end .container -->
   </div><!-- end .header -->  
         
  <div class="banner-wrap wsite-background">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="banner">
     <h2>{headline:text global="false"}</h2>
     <p>{headline-paragraph:text global="false"}</p> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main-wrap">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="content-wrap">{content}</div>
    </div><!-- end container -->
   </div>

    <div class="footer-wrap">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="footer">{footer}</div>
     </div><!-- end container -->
    </div><!-- end footer-wrap -->
 </div>

    <div class="nav mobile-nav">
        <label class="hamburger"><span></span></label>
        {menu}
    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/plugins.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your kids.html you have this, it overwrites your CSS-Code:

```
<style>
.wsite-background {background-image: url("//cdn1.editmysite.com/uploads/6/5/4/8/65485229/background-images/2036811843.jpg") !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-position: 50.00% 37.71% !important;background-size: 100% !important;background-color: transparent !important;}
body.wsite-background {background-attachment: fixed !important;}.wsite-background.wsite-custom-background{ background-size: cover !important}
</style>
```

Delete or Change this part of the code and it works:

```
.wsite-background.wsite-custom-background {
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

In your CSS-File you have this media query:
Explanation to media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
```

write this line of code in your media query:

```
.banner-wrap.wsite-background.wsite-custom-background{ background-size: 100% 100% !important; }
```

Its not perfect, an other solution whould be this, then you have to change the height of the element:

```
.banner-wrap.wsite-background.wsite-custom-background{ background-size: 100% auto !important; }
```

or this:

```
.banner-wrap.wsite-background.wsite-custom-background{ background-size: contain !important; }
```

Explanation to background-size: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately Weebly either generates the kids.html file dynamically, or they block users from editing it. I don't see it in the list of available files to edit.  :-/

Comment: Thank you. The "100% auto" one is about what I am after. However, as I expected, it is applying the change globally - to every single page that has a banner. I would prefer it not do it to my landing page. Is there a way to restrict it to pages of a certain type? Tall header pages? The kids.html is a tall-header type page. I'm attaching the tall-header.html code.

Comment: If you have acces to the html code, you could add a class in your html code to the element only in the html-files you want to change, like this: <div class="banner-wrap wsite-background custom"> and then in your css-code: .banner-wrap.wsite-background.custom